# Can not detect specific ble(Bluetooth Low Energy) on iOS 17

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral, ios17

My app has a tableView to display some ble devices.
The delegate method

```swift
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
optional func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
```

will filter some specific devices using `peripheral.name`

This worked fine on iOS 16.

But on iOS 17, `peripheral.name` for same ble devices return **`nil`**

I've searched this issue on Apple's Documentations for several hours. No result came out.

Is there any new API for `CBCentralManager`?

Comment: Sometimes it can be nil, but with doing a continuous scan (and the corresponding scan options), it can reappear with its name later one. It's been a while since I played with BLE, but if I remember correctly, it's because it reads "pieces by pieces of infos"  and couldn't get a name on first discover, but will on the second one.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for reply, I used other ble app such as **nRF Connect**, **LightBlue** on iOS 17, none of them could display `peripheral.name`, even the `advertisementData` is nil too.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Fault!

After I updated `Xcode` to `15.0.1`，`peripheral.name` is not nil any more, ble devices can be detected without any `code` changes.