# Xamarin BLE Scan In Background with iOS 17

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been utilizing the provided code to perform a Background BLE Scan within Xamarin, specifically targeting iOS projects. It has worked flawlessly until I updated my iOS device to version 17.

Below is the code snippet I'm currently using:

```
using CoreBluetooth;
using CoreLocation;
using Foundation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(iOSBleBackgroundBeaconScanService))]
namespace BLE_Scan_Background.iOS
{
    public class iOSBleBackgroundBeaconScanService : CBCentralManagerDelegate, IBleBackgroundBeaconScanService
    {
        public event IBleBackgroundBeaconScanService.OnDiscoverBleDeviceEventHandler OnDiscoverBleDeviceEvent;

        private static readonly ILogger? logger = BleMeshConstants.IsLoggingEnable ? DependencyService.Resolve<ILogger>() : null;

        private CBCentralManager cBCentralManager;

        /// <summary>
        /// The Uuids to use to scan for the devices
        /// If looking for any device this should be null
        /// </summary>
        private CBUUID[] cBUUIDs = new CBUUID[3]
        {
            CBUUID.FromString(BleBeaconDevicesEnum.BleBeaconDeviceUuids[0]),
            CBUUID.FromString(BleBeaconDevicesEnum.BleBeaconDeviceUuids[1]),
            CBUUID.FromString(BleBeaconDevicesEnum.BleBeaconDeviceUuids[2]),
        };

        private bool isRunning;

        public iOSBleBackgroundBeaconScanService()
        {
            cBCentralManager = new CBCentralManager(this, null);
        }

        public void StartBeaconScan(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            cancellationToken.Register(() => StopBeaconScan());

            // Log some information about the device's ble chip
            logger?.LogDebug("Ble Status: " + cBCentralManager.State);
            logger?.LogDebug("Authorizations: " + CBCentralManager.Authorization.ToString());

            // Set that a background service is running
            isRunning = true;

            // Check if the BleChip is already ON
            if (cBCentralManager.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn && cBCentralManager.IsScanning == false)
            {
                // Restart the scan
                cBCentralManager.ScanForPeripherals(cBUUIDs);
            }
        }

        public void StopBeaconScan()
        {
            // Stop the scan
            cBCentralManager?.StopScan();
            // cBCentralManager?.Dispose();

            // Set that a background process is no longer running
            isRunning = false;
        }

        public bool SupportsExtendedAdv()
        {
            return CBCentralManager.SupportsFeatures(CBCentralManagerFeature.ExtendedScanAndConnect);
        }

        public override void DiscoveredPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSDictionary advertisementData, NSNumber RSSI)
        {
            // Log some data about the newly scanned device
            logger?.LogDebug("Device Name: " + peripheral.Name);
            //logger?.LogDebug( "Device UUID: " + peripheral.UUID.ToString() );
            logger?.LogDebug("Device RSSI: " + RSSI.ToString());
            // Maybe add servicedata and localdata of advertisementdata
            //logger?.LogDebug(advertisementData);

            // Check the name of the device
            if (peripheral.Name.isCustomerDevice())
            {
                // Find the "Service Data" key
                foreach (var key in advertisementData.Keys)
                {
                    // Look for the ServiceData data
                    if (key.ToString() == "kCBAdvDataManufacturerData")
                    {
                        // Maybe check here if the ServiceData is correct?

                        // The service data in iOS lack of the first 2 bytes
                        // // 1: Data length, 2: Data type
                        // // But Android leaves them and are also used for the parsing of the adv data
                        // // So here are added "hard-code"
                        byte[] advData = new byte[] { 29, 255 }.Concat(((NSData)(advertisementData["kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"])).ToArray());
                        // Also append the device name because of what written before
                        // But before check if there is a device name
                        foreach (var sKey in advertisementData.Keys)
                        {
                            if (sKey.ToString() == "kCBAdvDataLocalName" && peripheral.Name is not null)
                            {
                                advData = advData.Concat(new byte[] { (byte)(peripheral.Name.Length + 1), 0x09 }).Concat(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(peripheral.Name)); // 0x09 is for complete local name
                            }
                        }
                        OnDiscoverBleDeviceEvent?.Invoke(advData, peripheral.Name);

                        logger?.LogDebug("Device Manufacturer Data: " + BitConverter.ToString(advData));
                    }
                }
                // Return an empty event ( this is needed for test scan )
                OnDiscoverBleDeviceEvent?.Invoke(null, peripheral.Name);
            }

            // This should be started only if the application has gone background
            cBCentralManager.ScanForPeripherals(cBUUIDs);
        }

        public override void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager central)
        {
            if (cBCentralManager.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
            {
                //cBCentralManager.ScanForPeripherals(cBUUIDs);
            }
            else // In this case just stop the scan. Maybe do something else?
            {
                cBCentralManager.StopScan();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this exact code on iPhones running iOS 16, specifically on an iPhone 8 and an iPhone 12 Pro, and it functioned seamlessly without any issues. However, upon updating one of my devices to iOS 17, the functionality appears to have been affected.

My question is twofold: Is this issue exclusive to iOS 17, or do I need to make adjustments to my code to ensure compatibility with newer iOS versions?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What is your Xcode version? Have you tried to upgrade to `Xcode 15.0.1`? Also, you can refer to this related issue:[Can not detect specific ble(Bluetooth Low Energy) on iOS 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77278108/can-not-detect-specific-blebluetooth-low-energy-on-ios-17).

Comment: Yes, I have. I didn't specify earlier, but throughout all the tests, I've been using Xcode version 15.2.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any error log when running on iOS 17? Also, you can report the issue to github:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues